# Problem uploading app to itunes connect: Info.plist keys - How to solve this one?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

Just a short question. Hopefully it's easy to solve!

I ran into these three problems uploading my app to appstore:

1. ITMS-90078: Missing Push Notification Entitlement

This one is easy to fix, even tho I don't know why it's appearing. I do not use Push Notifications in my app, I guess this is mandatory nowadays.

2 & 3. ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist

Both NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription and NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription.

I do use a third-party API which performs http requests, receiving json-data. Is this part of the problem or why do this appear? I do not use location in my app at all. I wonder what I should write in the string also, considering that I am not using the position data.

Best regards,
Rusben

Comment: if you are not using location, position or related to maps then you can remove `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` and `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` from your .plist file

Comment: if you don't want push notifications then you can go to --> click on project --> capabilities --> turn off the push notification

Comment: @NiravKotecha I am not using neither of those capabilities, but Apple reject my app due to missing key for those capabilities, and that's the problem. I do not understand why they insist on adding those keys. I do use a third-party API where I get data, could that be the reason why Apple rejects the app?

Comment: which third-part API you used ? and for what purpose you used ?

Comment: @NiravKotecha it's an API for currency rates, it's based on ECB, european central bank exchange rates.